# Scala collection memory footprint characteristics

Tags: scala, scala-collections

There is a handy page about [performance characteristics of the Scala collection classes](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_40.html). Is there similar data on memory footprint?

I have a situation where I'm concerned about memory use and would like to factor this in my choice of collection to use. For instance, between `Array[Array[T]]` and `Vector[Vector[T]]`.

Comment: Don't you know how to initialize a big Array of Arrays or Vector of Vector? Or don't you know how to measure the memory footprint? I would expect a linear relationship, and try to disprove or prove this idea for some forms of collection. Then measure for some sample sizes up to the limit of my machine.

Comment: It's more that I haven't performed those measurements and was wondering if anybody knew...

Answer (score 17):

Here is what I've found out by filling up those respective immutable sequences with 1,000,000 objects on 2.9.0. I had them all point to the same object to factor out the size of the content.

- `Array`: 1x *(baseline 4,000,016 bytes on 32 bits; 8,000,024 on 64 bits)*
- `Vector`: 1.17x
- `List`, `Queue`, `Stack`: 4x
- evaluated `Stream`: 10x

`System.gc` was called then triggered heap dump then opened in Eclipse MAT.

Based on that `Array` and `Vector` are pretty closed.

Comment: Vectors can't hold primitives (because they are not specialized (yet?)) but Arrays can. So an Array[Int] would take much less memory than Vector[Int].

Answer (score 1):

You could start with a simple generation of multiple, multidimensional Vectors and Arrays of different size:

```
val vMin = Vector.fill (10  , 10)(9)
val vMed = Vector.fill (1000, 10)(9)
val aMed =  Array.fill (1000, 10)(9)
```

10 Arrays of 10 Arrays of Ints with Value 9, 1000 such Arrays, 1000 such Vectors ...

To measure the size, you could use

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/jvisualvm
```