# Best performant immutable Seq for measuring length

Tags: scala, immutability, scala-collections

For whatever reason there was no notion on that in [Performance Characteristics Doc](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html), so I dug into the sources and found out that `List` and `Queue` seem to have *O(n)*, since they iterate thru all members. The `Vector` seems to have *O(1)*, since it simply subtracts one `Int` from another.

Now, it doesn't matter whether the collection is append- or prepend-oriented, but either one of them must be *O(1)*, and there's no need for performant `apply`.

Is `Vector` the correct choice? Which would you suggest?

Comment: There are very few situations where a `List` is better than a `Vector`. Default to `Vector` unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge Are you suggesting to use `Vector` as a default `Seq` implementation? This opinion seems at least unusual to me, because linked lists are all over the functional programming world and are the default collection type. Also `Vector`, being a more complex structure, must inevitably perform worse when used for `head`, `tail` and `prepend` operations. It must occupy more memory aswell. Could you please refer to any research / discussion / reading material on this?

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928327/when-should-i-choose-vector-in-scala)

Comment: Also interesting: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243232/scala-collection-memory-footprint-characteristics) showing that `Vector` has better memory footprint than `List`. There _was_ a discussion on one of the mailing lists about `Vector` as default type for `scala.Seq`, but I couldn't find it any more.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge Thanks. The answers on the first link kinda prove that `List` is better when you know what you're doing (i.e. head, tail and prepend), the `Vector` while being just slightly slower on those operations is well optimized for most of the others and thus makes a better candidate for general type of collection.

Comment: I'm glad @0__ found those links because they're what I was thinking of. I seem to have written an answer there lauding the virtues of `List`, but Daniel Spiewak knows a lot more about these things and I've come round to his view of favouring `Vector`. There's a good talk by him here: http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Functional-Data-Structures-in-Scala About the 26m mark he starts talking about hash tries, which is what Vector is, and why they're so efficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is Vector the correct choice?

Yes. An alternative would be to create your own immutable wrapper around List, adding its size as constant, but it would be a lot of work if you want to allow all standard collection operations. Stick to `Vector`.

Comment: Thanks! And for the links in comments too